# Report Builder vs Visual Studio on Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have this problem.
I created an ssrs report on Visual Studio for dynamics AX 2012.
Then I modified the report (don't ask me why) on Report Builder.
Now I open again it with Visual Studio but i don't see modifies from Report Builder.
How I can do that?
thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say but if you modified the deployed version of the report with RB and you are opening a local version of the report with VS this may be the problem.

When you save the report with Visual Studio and Visual Studio Tools and you deploy the modifications, the report is uploaded to the AOT (to the Model Store) at the same time.

When you open a report with reportbuilder you are editing the published version, but when you save and deploy the changes it won't be uploaded to the AOT copy of the object, so if you open  it from Visual Studio you won't see any change.

Comment: so, there isn't a chance to view any changes from VS?